# Rewrite only if Image don't exists with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, rewrite, rewritecond

How do I make RewriteCond+RewriteRule change site1.com/folder1 to site2.com/folder1, only if file in this directory don't exist.
For example: site1.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/image.jpg

If image site1.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/image.jpg  don't exists,
than get site2.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/image.jpg
But if image exists, don't do anything.

Update, here code what i need, thanks all for help )

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/uploads/"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} .*\.(jpeg|jpg|gif|png)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.+) http://site2.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Do you want a solution for just the example you have given or for *any* image on `site1.com`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this.

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILE} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site2.com/$1 [QSA,R,L]`

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# the above ignores any url for a file that exists on the site
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# the above ignores any url for a directory that exists on the site
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://[NEW_DOMAIN]/$1 [QSA,R,L]
# Redirect to another site and remain the same URL
```